# hadoop hbase compare rows same table

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I want to write a map-reduce or multiple to compare rows with each other.

I can't figure a way to write it without doing everything in a reducer.

With milions of rows this might take me a lot to compare the entire dataset with eachother. how can I achieve this?

I don't care about PIG. This is a simple case that I will extend (something I can't do in PIG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some questions to ask is
1. Do you want to compare until the last record?
2. If yes, for above then may be, i fear you dont have a choice than depending on reducer to get entire data
3. If answer is no and you want to skip the rest of the set, when a specific comparison is made and satisfied, then you can verify that in map it self and dont write anything to mapper output. However, there will still be other maps running, so may be in this case, you should exit the job, once comparison succeeds

Comment: I was affraid I will get this answer :)